# Why do C++ istreams only allow formatted-reading into an existing variable?

Tags: c++, iostream, idioms, istream

In C++ (and  using the standard library facilities), if I want to read an integer from the standard input, I need to do this:

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
```

And looking at the [`std::istream` page on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream), it seems there is no function such as `std::cin.scan<int>()` which returns an `int` prvalue; nor is there a freestanding function `std::scan<int>(std::cin)` which does so.

My question is: Why?

It seems nonsensical to me to encourage people to:

1. Define and name variables they may not need (e.g. as opposed to `func_taking_an_int(std::cin.scan<int>())`.
2. Split the definition and the initialization of a variable

So what's the rationale of only supporting the operator form?

Now, I know C++ istreams go back decades, but it's still weird to me (not to mention that an extra method/function could have been added later on).

---

<sub>Motivation: I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72321943/1593077) and realized that, to our shame, we cannot offer the poster a better way to write their program other than using an uninitialized variable. I was assuming that, surely, we can help that poster bring the definition into the same statement as the initialization... but it seems we cannot.</sub>

Comment: In `func_taking_an_int(std::cin.magic<int>())` where would you check that the read was successful?

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Inside `scan()`. If it fails, it throws.

Comment: This seems like it'd make a great proposal. I'd personally prefer something more akin to python's `input()`, though. I'd also like an in-the-standard solution for Unicode that's not the half-baked garbage that gets pointed at today.

Comment: @sweenish: I was betting something like this must have been discussed and rejected...

Comment: @einpoklum how about an optional instead of throwing? I find IO failures to be too common to be "exceptional", so I'd rather make that explicit.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Well, the standard library doesn't use optionals for anything; also, if you wanted to go that way, it would be [`std::expected`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70571282/1593077).

Comment: @einpoklum std::expected is not standardized

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: It is. C++23.

Comment: @einpoklum that won't be out until at least 2026 ;) Compilers still don't support C++20 properly

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: But neither will anything else proposed for C++23, like the proposal you're suggesting. In fact, it's unlikely a new proposal could come in at any time before 2026.

Comment: @einpoklum did I suggest a proposal? I don't recall suggesting a proposal at all.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Sorry, I mistook sweenish' comment for yours.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
  auto const i = *std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin);
}
```

Note that this causes UB if `std::cin` doesn't have a valid `int`. You might expect it to throw an exception, but since iostreams predate exceptions, that is not how the API works. You should compare it with the end-iterator.

```
std::istream_iterator<int> it(std::cin), end;
auto const i = (it != end) ? *it : -1;
```

Finally, you might want to wrap that in a nice, reusable API:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <optional>

template <class T>
auto scan(std::istream& is) -> std::optional<T> {
  std::istream_iterator<int> it(std::cin), end;
  if (it != end) return std::optional(*it);
  return std::nullopt;
}

int main() {
  auto const i = scan<int>(std::cin);
  if (i) {
    return *i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: This is cool, but "there is one" is not the same as "you have to write it yourself."

Comment: @sweenish the very first snippet is exactly what OP wants, minus error-checking because iostream predates exceptions. And it's in the standard library.

Comment: `return std::optional(*it);` should be just `return *it;` But frankly, if you are going to write a scanning function that returns an `optional`, I wouldn't bother using `istream_iterator` at all, just check the return state of `operator>>` instead, eg: `template <class T> std::optional<T> scan(std::istream& is) { T t; if (std::cin >> t) return t; return std::nullopt; }`

Comment: Is it really UB? Doesn't it trigger an exception? Also why would I want to use an istream iterator in `scan()` rather than just define a local variable and return it? Relying on NRVO? Regardless, though - the suggestion is irrelevant to the question, in that I'm not asking what _could_ be written, but what's in the standard library.

Comment: @einpoklum Doesn't `std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)` address the salient parts of your question? i.e. no additional variable is needed.

Comment: @einpoklum the first and second snippets are using just std facilities, you can use them the way you described in the question.

Comment: @cigien: Well, I asked about istreams themselves; plus - they don't quite address it, ecause (1.) it's a bit of a "hijacking" of what's intended to be used for iteration, not a single action; (2.) verbose syntax (3.) requires user to be aware and correctly utilize lots of things at the same type (4.) the undefined behavior at end-of-file issue; what's up with that? :-( (5.) I really don't believe the answer to my question is "istreams don't have it because standard library designers expected people to dereference istream_iterators".

Comment: @einpoklum `std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)` is very similar to your `scan<int>(std::cin)` request, isn't it? IOstreams predate exceptions, you couldn't expect it to throw one. Just check for the end iterator, and there you go.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: `scan()` is an _example_. But what you've just said about iostreams predating exceptions is important - definitely merits being in an answer.